# how to achieve this layout for mobile menu (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap for a navbar. The navbar is ok in larger devives, but on mobile devices, when the navbar-toggler button appears and is clicked i want to change a little the bootstrap default mobile menu.

Im trying to achieve this layout below when the mobile button is clicked:

- the menu appears at right occupying just a certain width like 200px
- the menu appears in front of the content, not pushing the content below
- and each item have a gray border-bottom

[image]

Do you know how to get this layout? Im using the code below but without success:

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/uu9fpt4o/

**html**

```
<div class="container px-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

    <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold text-primary mr-auto" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-flex align-items-lg-center ml-auto pull-right ">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="content col">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.navbar{
      border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.background{
    background-color:orange;
}

.content{
  height:320px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've Updated your fiddle

**Try This :)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
 .navbar-collapse{
  position: absolute;
  width : 40%;
  z-index:2;
  right :-16px;
  top : 8px;
}
  .navbar-nav li {
    border: 3px solid white;
  }
  .navbar-nav li:first-child {
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-nav li:last-child {
    border-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

**Live Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/uu9fpt4o/4/

**Happy Cssing :)**